# How to create responses depending on which checkboxes are checked?

Tags: php, forms, jquery, checkbox

I need some help.
I'm making a site that has a form, and the response text (is to be displayed immidiately after checking a box) is depending on which checkboxes is checked. Something like [this example at the bottom](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) only checkboxes, not radio buttons, and a little more complex than that.

It's three checkboxes, so it's five scenarios;

```
1 - 2 - 3
---------
O - O - O
X - O - O
X - X - O
X - O - X
X - X - X
```

I want to have 5 different responses, and was wondering how to do it. I've used AJAX a little bit before, but I don't remember much.. I was thinking that the responses could be parsed from a php-file with get-parameters.. but I don't know. *I don't all the responses and conditions to be written in jquery/javascript*.

So! Could anyone help me? :) Hopefully I've written good enough for you to understand my problem!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think three checkboxes make 2^3 = 8 scenarios.

Comment: Nico: I've tried to clearify the topic a bit now XD
Sahil & Alec: yeah, but in my case it's only 5 :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy way to make this work. You'll have to embed the [Jquery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). The POST parameters is processed by response.php. The form is submitted every time someone changes the state of one of the checkboxes, and the response is updated in the output-div.

```
<head> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="formId" name="formName" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Check[]" value="1" class="check"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Check[]" value="2" class="check"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Check[]" value="3" class="check"/>
  </form>

<div id = "output"></div>
<script>
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        target: '#output', // target element(s) to be updated with server response
        url: 'response.php' // override for form's 'action' attribute
    };

    $('.check').change(function() {
        $('#formId').ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the page you linked about the :checked selector is probably the most useful thing in this context.

I'm not really sure if there's a smooth way to determine what combination of them are checked.  I suppose you could give each one a different binary value (1, 2, 4), and sum the values of all of the checked boxes?

Then you could associate each possible sum with a different response call.

Of course, if you are dealing with the response on the server side, it could be a bit easier, because the server code should get each of those values as a list.

Not sure if it's helpful, but in Python I could handle something like this on the server this way:

```
RESPONSES = [
    function_1,
    ...,
    function_8]
def handle_checkboxes(request):
    response_code = sum(list(request.params["checkboxes"]))
    response = RESPONSES[response_code]()
    return response
```

I imagine it would be roughly the same in PHP. Of course, if you are planning to handle this on the client side, the code would be a bit different. But pretty much the same concept.

Comment: Hi, that's what I thought as well. However if I sum the different values some of them would return the same value. 1+2 and only 3 for instance. I thought that it would be an option to return a text string and extend it for each value checked. if 1 and 3 is checked the text string would be "chk=1&chk=3" and then send the text string to a php script that reads the GET-parameters and return a response via XHR.

Comment: That's why you use binary values (1, 2, 4 in this case), because then each possible combination produces a unique output.

Comment: ah, sorry. I didn't see that!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".checks").click(function(){

                    one = $("#one").attr("checked");    
                two = $("#two").attr("checked");
                three = $("#three").attr("checked");

                if(!one && !two && !three)
                {
                    alert("0-0-0");
                }
                else if(one && !two && !three)
                {
                    alert("1-0-0");
                }
                else if(one && two && !three)
                {
                    alert("1-1-0");
                }
                else if(one && !two && three)
                {
                    alert("1-0-1");
                }
                else if(one && two && three)
                {
                    alert("1-1-1");
                }

                       });              


                });

</script>
```

and html:

```
 <form>
 1<input type="checkbox" id="one" class="checks" /><br>
 2<input type="checkbox" id="two" class="checks" /><br>
 3<input type="checkbox" id="three" class="checks" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! But I wanted to use a XHR to return a response from a PHP file, and the conditions inside the PHP as well.. Using XHR and Get-parameters. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Javascript:

```
function countChecked() {
    var str="";
    a= $("#a").attr("checked");    
    b= $("#b").attr("checked");
    c= $("#c").attr("checked");

    if (a){ str+='X'; } else str+='0';

    str+='-';

    if (b){ str+='X'; }else  str+='0';

    str+='-';

    if (c){ str+='X'; }else  str+='0';

    $("div").text(str);
}
countChecked();
$(":checkbox").click(countChecked);
```

And here is the HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="a" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="b" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="c" value="3" />
<br>
<div></div>
```

You can also check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/medopal/Fmavs/)

Comment: Hi! thanks for you answer, however as I mentioned in the post (now emphasized) i'd like to write the conditions and the responses inside a php-file. Like sending a XHR to the php-file and checking the get-parameters. And the X's and O's was only to point out the scenarios. The response would be 5 different sentences.. Could you help me further? :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I know nothing about PHP, but I will the php tag, maybe someone else can help you.